# Numpy array custom dtype, array is not writable (IronPython)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ironpython, user-defined-types

I have a question to numpy arrays using in IronPython. I have a problem assigning values to array with custom dtype. I'm using example from http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

```
dt = np.dtype([('name', np.str_, 16), ('grades', np.float64, (2,))])
x = np.array([('Sarah', (8.0, 7.0)), ('John', (6.0, 7.0))], dtype=dt)
```

When I want to assign values to the `x` array by:

```
x[1][1][:]=np.array([6.2,5.1])
```

or

```
x[1][1][0]=6.2
```

I get

```
Message: array is not writeable.
```

Could be the problem in using IronPython? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: with CPython it works without any problems on my machine. It could be IronPython

Comment: Thanks @flebool. I thought, it could be the problem. So is there another way when I (probably) can't use custom dtype?

Comment: @frenezulo did you try to use simply `dtype=object`?

Comment: Yeah, @SaulloCastro, it came to my mind to use dtype=object. But I'm not sure now, it worked. I finally managed it with only one level of the array, eg. ('Sarah', 8.0, 7.0).